# Flutter Persistent_bottom_nav_bar package

Tags: flutter

I'm using the persistent_bottom_nav_bar package in my project, I've been working on retrieving the page index (controller.index) on moving from from tab to the other which doesn't work. It only gets updated when I reload the app. Any help please.

Comment: add your code snippet

Comment: add your code then we can help you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [example](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar), onItemSelected can be used to get the index:

```
         onItemSelected: (int) {
             setState(() {}); // This is required to update the nav bar if Android back button is pressed
         },
```